# How to use XUnit Collection Fixtures in ABP?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xunit, aspnetboilerplate, fixtures

We have a .NET Core 2.2 project using ASP.NET Boilerplate 4.10.1.

This project has a huge db context that takes way too long to load for each integration test we're running, so we'd like to see how it'd go with a shared context between tests.

Unfortunately, we're unable to figure out how to combine [XUnit collection fixtures](https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context#collection-fixture) with ABP, and found no documentation on the matter.

Some of our code, if it helps:

```
public abstract class EcfTestBase : AbpIntegratedTestBase<EcfTestBaseModule>
{
    protected EcfTestBase()
    {
        AbpSession.TenantId = null;
        UsingDbContext(context =>
        {
            NormalizeDbContext(context);
            // Seed initial data for host
            SeedHelper.SeedHostDb(context);
        });

        // Seed initial data for default tenant
        AbpSession.TenantId = 1;
        UsingDbContext(context =>
        {
            NormalizeDbContext(context);
        });

        LoginAsDefaultTenantAdmin();

        void NormalizeDbContext(EcfDbContext context)
        {
            context.EntityChangeEventHelper = NullEntityChangeEventHelper.Instance;
            context.EventBus = NullEventBus.Instance;
            context.SuppressAutoSetTenantId = true;
        }
    }
```

Integration test:

```
public class Reg0000Controller_Tests : EcfTestBase
{
    private readonly Reg0000AppService _Reg0000AppService;

    public Reg0000Controller_Tests()
    {
        _Reg0000AppService = Resolve<Reg0000AppService>();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task Reg0000_Create()
    {
        using (var controller = new Reg0000Controller(_Reg0000AppService))
        {
            var result = await controller.Create(new Reg0000Dto
            {
                CenarioId = 1,                        
                Nome = "Empresa Teste"
            });

            result.Nome.ShouldBe("Empresa Teste");
            await UsingDbContextAsync(async context =>
            {
                var reg0000 = await context.Reg0000.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Nome == "Empresa Teste");
                reg0000.ShouldNotBeNull();
                reg0000.CreatorUserId.ShouldNotBeNull();
                reg0000.CreationTime.ShouldNotBeNull();
                reg0000.LastModifierUserId.ShouldBeNull();
            });
        }
```

Comment: Don't use a huge DbContext. It's as simple as that. A DbContext is essentially a Unit of Work and should *only* contain the DbSets needed for it to do its job. If you're into DDD think about bounded contexts. You should read [No need for repositories and unit of work with Entity Framework Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/) too. ABP generates some pretty horrible EF and data access code.